# Grouping, counting and sorting collection takes too long. How can I improve my Laravel code?

Tags: php, laravel

In my app, there are several businesses, each business can have multiple orders, and each order can have various products. To get all business orders, including products (relation), I use `$orders = $business->orders()->with('products')->get();` I need to calculate the quantity how often the product is ordered, in other words, the number of times I see each product in my orders.

So after `get()`, I have the following results.

```
[
    {
        "id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
        "business_id": "8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77",
        "user_id": null,
        "business_customer_id": null,
        "customer_name": " Nitin",
        "customer_email": "nitin@hit-pay.com",
        "customer_phone_number": "123123",
        "customer_street": "#16-31, 5A LORONG HOW SUN,  Bartley Residences, SINGAPORE 536563",
        "customer_city": "Singapore",
        "customer_state": "Singapore",
        "customer_postal_code": "536563",
        "customer_country": "sg",
        "customer_pickup": 0,
        "channel": "store_checkout",
        "currency": "sgd",
        "automatic_discount_name": "amount discount",
        "automatic_discount_amount": 500,
        "line_item_price": 3000,
        "line_item_discount_amount": 0,
        "line_item_tax_amount": 0,
        "automatic_discount_reason": null,
        "additional_discount_amount": 0,
        "business_shipping_id": "937d5b59-b449-4901-a685-e208460f426c",
        "shipping_method": "Shipping Not Applicable",
        "shipping_amount": 0,
        "shipping_tax_name": null,
        "shipping_tax_rate": "0.0000",
        "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
        "slot_date": null,
        "slot_time": null,
        "amount": 2500,
        "coupon_amount": 0,
        "tax_setting_id": null,
        "reference": null,
        "messages": null,
        "remark": null,
        "status": "requires_business_action",
        "executor_id": null,
        "request_ip_address": "116.86.78.44",
        "request_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.1 Safari/605.1.15",
        "request_method": "post",
        "request_url": "https://staging.myshop.sg/8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77/checkout",
        "request_country": null,
        "request_data": {
            "device": {
                "name": "Macintosh",
                "type": "computer"
            },
            "browser": {
                "name": "Safari",
                "version": "14.1.1"
            },
            "platform": {
                "name": "OS X",
                "version": "10_15_7"
            },
            "referrer": "https://staging.myshop.sg/8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77/checkout",
            "requests": {
                "email": "nitin@hit-pay.com",
                "discount": {
                    "name": "amount discount",
                    "amount": 500
                },
                "shipping": {
                    "option": "937d5b59-b449-4901-a685-e208460f426c",
                    "address": {
                        "city": "Singapore",
                        "state": "Singapore",
                        "street": "#16-31, 5A LORONG HOW SUN,  Bartley Residences, SINGAPORE 536563",
                        "country": "sg",
                        "postal_code": "536563"
                    }
                },
                "last_name": "Nitin",
                "phone_number": "123123"
            }
        },
        "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:50:07",
        "expires_at": null,
        "closed_at": null,
        "products_count": 2,
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "94567311-e669-4943-b90e-537669099bc2",
                "business_order_id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
                "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338",
                "stock_keeping_unit": null,
                "name": "Black Tote Bag",
                "description": "Small",
                "weight": null,
                "length": null,
                "width": null,
                "depth": null,
                "variation_key_1": "Size",
                "variation_value_1": "Small",
                "variation_key_2": null,
                "variation_value_2": null,
                "variation_key_3": null,
                "variation_value_3": null,
                "quantity": 1,
                "tax_name": null,
                "tax_rate": "0.0000",
                "unit_price": 1500,
                "tax_amount": 0,
                "discount_amount": 0,
                "price": 1500,
                "remark": null,
                "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
                "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
                "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            {
                "id": "94567311-e6bb-48b4-8bdf-ad282dcc6d72",
                "business_order_id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
                "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-7781-4d9a-859e-8296669a9926",
                "stock_keeping_unit": null,
                "name": "Black Tote Bag",
                "description": "Medium",
                "weight": null,
                "length": null,
                "width": null,
                "depth": null,
                "variation_key_1": "Size",
                "variation_value_1": "Medium",
                "variation_key_2": null,
                "variation_value_2": null,
                "variation_key_3": null,
                "variation_value_3": null,
                "quantity": 1,
                "tax_name": null,
                "tax_rate": "0.0000",
                "unit_price": 1500,
                "tax_amount": 0,
                "discount_amount": 0,
                "price": 1500,
                "remark": null,
                "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
                "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
                "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
                "deleted_at": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "94606929-ab27-49c1-b8da-21cefee04e7a",
        "business_id": "8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77",
        "user_id": null,
        "business_customer_id": null,
        "customer_name": " H",
        "customer_email": "test@gmail.com",
        "customer_phone_number": "0290839918",
        "customer_street": "Dn",
        "customer_city": "Dn",
        "customer_state": "Dn",
        "customer_postal_code": "550000",
        "customer_country": "sg",
        "customer_pickup": 0,
        "channel": "store_checkout",
        "currency": "sgd",
        "automatic_discount_name": "amount discount",
        "automatic_discount_amount": 500,
        "line_item_price": 3500,
        "line_item_discount_amount": 0,
        "line_item_tax_amount": 0,
        "automatic_discount_reason": null,
        "additional_discount_amount": 0,
        "business_shipping_id": "937d5b59-b449-4901-a685-e208460f426c",
        "shipping_method": "Shipping Not Applicable",
        "shipping_amount": 0,
        "shipping_tax_name": null,
        "shipping_tax_rate": "0.0000",
        "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
        "slot_date": null,
        "slot_time": null,
        "amount": 3000,
        "coupon_amount": 0,
        "tax_setting_id": null,
        "reference": null,
        "messages": null,
        "remark": null,
        "status": "requires_business_action",
        "executor_id": null,
        "request_ip_address": "14.185.167.6",
        "request_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:92.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/92.0",
        "request_method": "post",
        "request_url": "https://staging.myshop.sg/8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77/checkout",
        "request_country": null,
        "request_data": {
            "device": {
                "type": "computer"
            },
            "browser": {
                "name": "Firefox",
                "version": "92.0"
            },
            "platform": {
                "name": "Windows",
                "version": "10.0"
            },
            "referrer": "https://staging.myshop.sg/8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77/checkout",
            "requests": {
                "email": "test@gmail.com",
                "discount": {
                    "name": "amount discount",
                    "amount": 500
                },
                "shipping": {
                    "option": "937d5b59-b449-4901-a685-e208460f426c",
                    "address": {
                        "city": "Dn",
                        "state": "Dn",
                        "street": "Dn",
                        "country": "sg",
                        "postal_code": "550000"
                    }
                },
                "last_name": "H",
                "phone_number": "0290839918"
            }
        },
        "created_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-12 11:41:38",
        "expires_at": null,
        "closed_at": null,
        "products_count": 2,
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "94606929-ad05-4c67-9491-644e8d3b434b",
                "business_order_id": "94606929-ab27-49c1-b8da-21cefee04e7a",
                "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338",
                "stock_keeping_unit": null,
                "name": "Black Tote Bag",
                "description": "Small",
                "weight": null,
                "length": null,
                "width": null,
                "depth": null,
                "variation_key_1": "Size",
                "variation_value_1": "Small",
                "variation_key_2": null,
                "variation_value_2": null,
                "variation_key_3": null,
                "variation_value_3": null,
                "quantity": 1,
                "tax_name": null,
                "tax_rate": "0.0000",
                "unit_price": 1500,
                "tax_amount": 0,
                "discount_amount": 0,
                "price": 1500,
                "remark": null,
                "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
                "created_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
                "updated_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
                "deleted_at": null
            },
            {
                "id": "94606929-ad66-4a69-93ae-1e291c2d7e53",
                "business_order_id": "94606929-ab27-49c1-b8da-21cefee04e7a",
                "business_product_id": "93253bf2-ce63-4a9a-b4a6-8ecaff439028",
                "stock_keeping_unit": null,
                "name": "Bynd Artisan Tote Bag Duplicate",
                "description": "Blue / Small",
                "weight": null,
                "length": null,
                "width": null,
                "depth": null,
                "variation_key_1": "Color",
                "variation_value_1": "Blue",
                "variation_key_2": "Size",
                "variation_value_2": null,
                "variation_key_3": null,
                "variation_value_3": null,
                "quantity": 1,
                "tax_name": null,
                "tax_rate": "0.0000",
                "unit_price": 2000,
                "tax_amount": 0,
                "discount_amount": 0,
                "price": 2000,
                "remark": null,
                "business_image_id": "93253bf2-e5c2-4a22-8605-81c245bcf86b",
                "created_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
                "updated_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
                "deleted_at": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "94606a50-2a40-476e-bd71-50c096270174",
        "business_id": "8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77",
        "user_id": null,
        "business_customer_id": null,
        "customer_name": " nitin",
        "customer_email": "nitin@hit-pay.com",
        "customer_phone_number": "9000123123",
        "customer_street": "test",
        "customer_city": "sg",
        "customer_state": "singapore",
        "customer_postal_code": "600123",
        "customer_country": "sg",
        "customer_pickup": 0,
        "channel": "store_checkout",
        "currency": "sgd",
        "automatic_discount_name": "% discount",
        "automatic_discount_amount": 200,
        "line_item_price": 2000,
        "line_item_discount_amount": 0,
        "line_item_tax_amount": 0,
        "automatic_discount_reason": null,
        "additional_discount_amount": 0,
        "business_shipping_id": "937d5b59-b449-4901-a685-e208460f426c",
        "shipping_method": "Shipping Not Applicable",
        "shipping_amount": 0,
        "shipping_tax_name": null,
        "shipping_tax_rate": "0.0000",
        "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
        "slot_date": null,
        "slot_time": null,
        "amount": 1800,
        "coupon_amount": 0,
        "tax_setting_id": null,
        "reference": null,
        "messages": null,
        "remark": "test",
        "status": "requires_business_action",
        "executor_id": null,
        "request_ip_address": "116.86.78.44",
        "request_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.1 Safari/605.1.15",
        "request_method": "post",
        "request_url": "https://staging.myshop.sg/8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77/checkout",
        "request_country": null,
        "request_data": {
            "device": {
                "name": "Macintosh",
                "type": "computer"
            },
            "browser": {
                "name": "Safari",
                "version": "14.1.1"
            },
            "platform": {
                "name": "OS X",
                "version": "10_15_7"
            },
            "referrer": "https://staging.myshop.sg/8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77/checkout",
            "requests": {
                "email": "nitin@hit-pay.com",
                "remark": "test",
                "discount": {
                    "name": "% discount",
                    "amount": 200
                },
                "shipping": {
                    "option": "937d5b59-b449-4901-a685-e208460f426c",
                    "address": {
                        "city": "sg",
                        "state": "singapore",
                        "street": "test",
                        "country": "sg",
                        "postal_code": "600123"
                    }
                },
                "last_name": "nitin",
                "phone_number": "9000123123"
            }
        },
        "created_at": "2021-09-12 11:43:34",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-12 11:44:02",
        "expires_at": null,
        "closed_at": null,
        "products_count": 1,
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "94606a50-2bac-48b8-860f-eebec27aff8d",
                "business_order_id": "94606a50-2a40-476e-bd71-50c096270174",
                "business_product_id": "93253bf2-ce63-4a9a-b4a6-8ecaff439028",
                "stock_keeping_unit": null,
                "name": "Bynd Artisan Tote Bag Duplicate",
                "description": "Blue / Small",
                "weight": null,
                "length": null,
                "width": null,
                "depth": null,
                "variation_key_1": "Color",
                "variation_value_1": "Blue",
                "variation_key_2": "Size",
                "variation_value_2": null,
                "variation_key_3": null,
                "variation_value_3": null,
                "quantity": 1,
                "tax_name": null,
                "tax_rate": "0.0000",
                "unit_price": 2000,
                "tax_amount": 0,
                "discount_amount": 0,
                "price": 2000,
                "remark": null,
                "business_image_id": "93253bf2-e5c2-4a22-8605-81c245bcf86b",
                "created_at": "2021-09-12 11:43:34",
                "updated_at": "2021-09-12 11:43:34",
                "deleted_at": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "9466c9d9-2a57-4551-b36b-294b64fb9fe4",
        "business_id": "8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77",
        "user_id": null,
        "business_customer_id": null,
        "customer_name": " Test",
        "customer_email": "test@gmail.com",
        "customer_phone_number": "092028028",
        "customer_street": "DN",
        "customer_city": "DN",
        "customer_state": "DN",
        "customer_postal_code": "550000",
        "customer_country": "sg",
        "customer_pickup": 0,
        "channel": "store_checkout",
        "currency": "sgd",
        "automatic_discount_name": "% discount",
        "automatic_discount_amount": 200,
        "line_item_price": 2000,
        "line_item_discount_amount": 0,
        "line_item_tax_amount": 0,
        "automatic_discount_reason": null,
        "additional_discount_amount": 0,
        "business_shipping_id": "937d5b59-b449-4901-a685-e208460f426c",
        "shipping_method": "Shipping Not Applicable",
        "shipping_amount": 0,
        "shipping_tax_name": null,
        "shipping_tax_rate": "0.0000",
        "shipping_tax_amount": 0,
        "slot_date": null,
        "slot_time": null,
        "amount": 1800,
        "coupon_amount": 0,
        "tax_setting_id": null,
        "reference": null,
        "messages": null,
        "remark": null,
        "status": "requires_business_action",
        "executor_id": null,
        "request_ip_address": "14.185.201.146",
        "request_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36",
        "request_method": "post",
        "request_url": "https://staging.myshop.sg/8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77/checkout",
        "request_country": null,
        "request_data": {
            "device": {
                "name": "WebKit",
                "type": "computer"
            },
            "browser": {
                "name": "Chrome",
                "version": "93.0.4577.63"
            },
            "platform": {
                "name": "Windows",
                "version": "10.0"
            },
            "referrer": "https://staging.myshop.sg/8ba6c772-8c2d-4f3b-a7d6-3f1f0648fa77/checkout",
            "requests": {
                "email": "test@gmail.com",
                "discount": {
                    "name": "% discount",
                    "amount": 200
                },
                "shipping": {
                    "option": "937d5b59-b449-4901-a685-e208460f426c",
                    "address": {
                        "city": "DN",
                        "state": "DN",
                        "street": "DN",
                        "country": "sg",
                        "postal_code": "550000"
                    }
                },
                "last_name": "Test",
                "phone_number": "092028028"
            }
        },
        "created_at": "2021-09-15 15:45:40",
        "updated_at": "2021-09-15 15:46:08",
        "expires_at": null,
        "closed_at": null,
        "products_count": 1,
        "products": [
            {
                "id": "9466c9d9-3131-43f7-99f3-c41ccd3308d1",
                "business_order_id": "9466c9d9-2a57-4551-b36b-294b64fb9fe4",
                "business_product_id": "93253bf2-ce63-4a9a-b4a6-8ecaff439028",
                "stock_keeping_unit": null,
                "name": "Bynd Artisan Tote Bag Duplicate",
                "description": "Blue / Small",
                "weight": null,
                "length": null,
                "width": null,
                "depth": null,
                "variation_key_1": "Color",
                "variation_value_1": "Blue",
                "variation_key_2": "Size",
                "variation_value_2": null,
                "variation_key_3": null,
                "variation_value_3": null,
                "quantity": 1,
                "tax_name": null,
                "tax_rate": "0.0000",
                "unit_price": 2000,
                "tax_amount": 0,
                "discount_amount": 0,
                "price": 2000,
                "remark": null,
                "business_image_id": "93253bf2-e5c2-4a22-8605-81c245bcf86b",
                "created_at": "2021-09-15 15:45:40",
                "updated_at": "2021-09-15 15:45:40",
                "deleted_at": null
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Using the following code, I achieved exactly what I wanted:

```
$orders = $business->orders()->with('products')->get();

        foreach ($orders as $order){
            foreach ($order->products as $product)
                $subset[] = $product;
        }

        $groupedOrderedProducts = collect($subset)->groupBy('business_product_id');

        $topProducts = $groupedOrderedProducts->map(function ($product){
            return ['product' => $product->first(),'count'=>$product->count()];
        })->sortByDesc('count');
```

**Results:**

```
{
    "93253bf2-ce63-4a9a-b4a6-8ecaff439028": {
        "product": {
            "id": "94606929-ad66-4a69-93ae-1e291c2d7e53",
            "business_order_id": "94606929-ab27-49c1-b8da-21cefee04e7a",
            "business_product_id": "93253bf2-ce63-4a9a-b4a6-8ecaff439028",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Bynd Artisan Tote Bag Duplicate",
            "description": "Blue / Small",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Color",
            "variation_value_1": "Blue",
            "variation_key_2": "Size",
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 2000,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 2000,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "93253bf2-e5c2-4a22-8605-81c245bcf86b",
            "created_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-12 11:40:21",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        "count": 4
    },
    "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338": {
        "product": {
            "id": "94567311-e669-4943-b90e-537669099bc2",
            "business_order_id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
            "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-762d-4caf-a3af-ea0359906338",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Black Tote Bag",
            "description": "Small",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Size",
            "variation_value_1": "Small",
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1500,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1500,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
            "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        "count": 3
    },
    "92df0ca8-7781-4d9a-859e-8296669a9926": {
        "product": {
            "id": "94567311-e6bb-48b4-8bdf-ad282dcc6d72",
            "business_order_id": "94567311-e554-4265-8753-db5d021f0544",
            "business_product_id": "92df0ca8-7781-4d9a-859e-8296669a9926",
            "stock_keeping_unit": null,
            "name": "Black Tote Bag",
            "description": "Medium",
            "weight": null,
            "length": null,
            "width": null,
            "depth": null,
            "variation_key_1": "Size",
            "variation_value_1": "Medium",
            "variation_key_2": null,
            "variation_value_2": null,
            "variation_key_3": null,
            "variation_value_3": null,
            "quantity": 1,
            "tax_name": null,
            "tax_rate": "0.0000",
            "unit_price": 1500,
            "tax_amount": 0,
            "discount_amount": 0,
            "price": 1500,
            "remark": null,
            "business_image_id": "92516d93-e06c-4718-b49a-8d63844ce5e5",
            "created_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "updated_at": "2021-09-07 12:49:46",
            "deleted_at": null
        },
        "count": 1
    }
}
```

I feel that my code is not the best solution. How can I improve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship for business and products, that way you can select the products of the business directly and group them.

```
$groupedOrderedProducts = $business->products()->groupBy('business_product_id')->get();
```